# Difference between predicted values and expected values of binary model

Tags: probability, binary

For a binary model with Y as the dependent variable and X1, X2, and X3 as independent variable, my understanding is that the predicted value is the value of Y at specified values of of X1,X2,X3. Ex. if LPM is Y = β1∗X1+β2∗X2+β3∗X3+ϵ. The predicted value (Y) for X1 = X2 = X3 = 1 is β1+β2+β3.

For expected value, is it the average of the predicted value at specified values for all the observations in the sample? I am kind of confused about the difference between the two. Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: Can you provide context for the way the two terms are used in the material you are using?

Comment: @FalafelPita It's a question on a practice exam and it just asked what the difference between the two values for binary model. There was no context in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The expected value is $E(Y)=\sum_{k=1}^{3}\beta_k E(X_k)$, ignoring $\epsilon$, which isn't explained.

Comment: Does this mean that we use the mean value of each independent variable to calculate the value for the dependent variable? We can't  just sum the value of the dependent variable for each observation up, then find the average of it. Am I getting it right?

Comment: E(X) is defined in terms of the underlying distribution function.  Using observations and taking an average is an approximation.